# One contract or several?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

How many contracts?

```
Contract.Requires(name.NotEmpty() && identifier.NotEmpty());
```

or

```
Contract.Requires(name.NotEmpty());
Contract.Requires(identifier.NotEmpty());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the second one for a couple of reasons

1. It scales to more contracts better
2. Depending on your code contract library and the quality of messages it produces it may be easier to see exactly which condition failed

Comment: Not just 'like better', it _is_ better.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely want the second form, independent Require statements for each parameter.

Remember that with the static checker this information is also used at the call-site(s). I believe the checker may be able to parse a `&&` condition but you don't want to know.

Answer (score 0):

the code as you have posted does exactly the same thing